# Xcode console outside Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, console

Is it possible to display the Xcode console of an application in real time on an iPhone/iPad without to need the computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the iPhone Configuration Utility at http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/ . It can display the console of any iOS device, as long as it's connected by USB. Runs on both MacOS and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need Xcode per se, but you do need to be connected to a Mac with a USB cable. The iPhone Configuration Utility is also able to view console logs of applications.